# Modify WIX to target specific SSRS instance

Tags: reporting-services, wix

I am using `Barcode Rendering Framework` with SSRS reports. In that they have WIX setup to use `VS2008` and `SSRS2008`. But I need to modify the source to deploy it on `VS2013` and `SSRS2014`.

For that I got the source and have updated project framework as well as dll according to the framework. Now, I stuck in WIX installer package. I am completely new to WIX. In that WIX project, they used the default SSRS instance to update config settings and deploy the necessary dlls.

I need to provide the target `SSRS Instance` as my SSRS server instance. Is there any way that i can modify the wix file to update it. Pl help me to fix it.

**Source of WIX**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?include ..\Versioning\SharedAssemblyFileVersion.wxi ?>
<!--
**** PLEASE NOTE THIS INSTALLER IS NOT YET COMPLETE!!!!! ****
**** TODO LIST ***
1. Test patching (small and minor)
2. Test upgrading (major)
3. Add UI for SSRS Instance selection

**** You will need at least WiX 3.6.3025.0 to build this ****
**** You will need SSRS2008 and VS2008 to build this ****

WiX installer capable of installing the Zen Barcode components to a SQL Server
Reporting Services 2008 system.
The installer comprises two features;
- Server Components
- Designtime Components

The server components will only install on systems where SSRS2008 has been     
detected.
The designtime components will only install on systems where VS2008 has been
detected.

The install file is written in such a manner as to facilitate the future 
addition of small updates and minor upgrade patches.

NOTE: There is no difference to the built binaries for x86 and x64 versions
however the registry search behaviour is different for these systems when
attempting to locate the SSRS installation folder.

Currently the installer will not allow multiple instances of itself to be
installed on the same machine (in cases where you wish to install to barcode
support to multiple SSRS instances on the same machine) as this requires a
significant amount of work... For installs of this type you'll have to do it
by hand - sorry! For anyone interested in knowing what is involved read on...
1. Installer product file (this file) must be modified to incorporate an
"instance-index". The instance index is used to change the product code
so that different instances have different product codes and thus MSI will
allow each one to install. The maximum number of instances is known 
beforehand - for example 16 instances. The instance index must be written
to the registry along with the SSRS Instance Name as part of installation.
2. Installer product file must be able to identify (using pre-processor symbols)
whether this is a baseline build, an instance transform build or a final build
3. Installer build script must be run once to create a baseline install
4. Installer build script must be run once for each supported instance to create a
an instance build and WiX torch must be used to generate transform from 
baseline to instance.
5. Installer build script must be run a final time and instance transforms must be
added to the binaries table.
6. Custom actions are needed to determine a free instance index (by scanning the registry)
Either as registry searches or as a custom piece of C++ code...
7. If this is not the first install then the appropriate transform must be enabled
before the install starts.
This means two custom actions to set the following properties;
TRANSFORMS=:instance.mst
MSINEWINSTANCE=1
-->
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
     RequiredVersion="3.6.3025.0">
<Product Id="*"
                 Name="Zen Barcode for Reporting Services v$(var.InstallVersion)"
                 Language="1033"
                 Version="$(var.InstallVersion)"
                 Manufacturer="Zen Design"
                 UpgradeCode="{C286DC9B-26E3-44EB-BB56-C88CFC6BDCA9}">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200"
                     Compressed="yes"
                     InstallScope="perMachine"
                     InstallPrivileges="elevated"
                     Keywords="Barcode,Installer,SSRS,CustomReportItem"
                     Description="Installer adding the barcode custom report item to SSRS."/>

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />

    <Media Id="1"
                 Cabinet="BarcodeSSRS.cab"
                 EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!-- Allow user to see feature tree -->
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />

    <!--
To install we need to copy our binaries to SSRS
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

Then modify two files located at
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer

Note: The instance name must be passed to MSIEXEC if installation to the non-default SSRS
instance is desired (using property SSRSINSTANCE)
TODO: Modify WiX dialogs to add a SSRS instance selector page.
-->

    <!-- 
SSRSINSTANCE - Specifies the SSRS instance to update.
-->
    <Property Id="SSRSINSTANCE"
                        Value="MSSQLSERVER"
                        Secure="yes" />

    <!--
SsrsKeyName - Determines the registry key name for the SSRS instance.
-->
    <Property Id="SSRSKEYNAME">
        <?if $(var.Platform) = "x86" ?>
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSInstanceKey"
                                        Root="HKLM"
                                        Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS"
                                        Name="[SSRSINSTANCE]"
                                        Type="raw"
                                        Win64="no" />
        <?else ?>
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSInstanceKey"
                                        Root="HKLM"
                                        Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS"
                                        Name="[SSRSINSTANCE]"
                                        Type="raw"
                                        Win64="yes" />
        <?endif ?>
    </Property>

    <!-- 
SSRSFOLDER - Determines the installation folder for the SSRS instance.
-->
    <Property Id="SSRSFOLDER">
        <?if $(var.Platform) = "x86" ?>
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSFolder"
                                        Root="HKLM"
                                        Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SSRSKEYNAME]\Setup"
                                        Name="SQLPath"
                                        Type="directory"
                                        Win64="no" />
        <?else ?>
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSFolder"
                                        Root="HKLM"
                                        Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SSRSKEYNAME]\Setup"
                                        Name="SQLPath"
                                        Type="directory"
                                        Win64="yes" />
        <?endif ?>
    </Property>

    <!--
VSIDEFOLDER - Determines the location of the Visual Studio environment.
NOTE: This assumes we are installing to Visual Studio 2008 and therefore
targetting SQL Server Reporting Services 2008.
-->
    <Property Id="VSIDEFOLDER">
        <RegistrySearch Id="GetVSFolder"
                                        Root="HKLM"
                                        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Setup\VS"
                                        Name="EnvironmentDirectory"
                                        Type="directory"
                                        Win64="no" />
    </Property>

    <FeatureRef Id="ProductFeature" />
</Product>

<!-- 
  The WiX parts are seperated into fragments as this makes any future small
  updates and minor version patches much easier to develop and deploy.
  -->

<!-- Main feature fragment -->
<Fragment>
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature"
                     Title="Zen Barcode for Reporting Services"
                     Level="1">
        <FeatureRef Id="ServerFeature" />
        <FeatureRef Id="DesignerFeature" />
    </Feature>
</Fragment>

<!-- Server feature fragment -->
<Fragment>
    <Feature Id="ServerFeature"
                     Title="Server Components"
                     Description="Installs components needed to extend Reporting Services to support reports containing barcodes."
                     Level="1">
        <Condition Level="0">
            <![CDATA[(SSRSKEYNAME = "") or (SSRSFOLDER = "")]]>
        </Condition>
        <ComponentRef Id="SsrsBarcodeRuntimeDllComponent" />
        <ComponentRef Id="SsrsBarcodeCoreDllComponent" />
    </Feature>
</Fragment>

<!-- Designtime feature fragment -->
<Fragment>
    <Feature Id="DesignerFeature"
                     Title="Designtime Components"
                     Description="Installs components needed to enable Visual Studio to create reports containing barcodes."
                     Level="1">
        <Condition Level="0">
            <![CDATA[(VSIDEFOLDER = "")]]>
        </Condition>
        <ComponentRef Id="VsBarcodeRuntimeDllComponent" />
        <ComponentRef Id="VsBarcodeDesigntimeDllComponent" />
        <ComponentRef Id="VsBarcodeCoreDllComponent" />
    </Feature>
</Fragment>

<!-- Install folder fragment -->
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR"
                         Name="SourceDir">
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<!-- SSRS folder fragments -->
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Directory Id="SSRSFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="ReportServerFolder"
                                 Name="ReportServer">
                <Directory Id="ReportServerBinFolder"
                                     Name="Bin">
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ReportServerBinFolder"
                                FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.TargetDir)">
        <Component Id="SsrsBarcodeRuntimeDllComponent"
                             Guid="{00A39E07-F512-420C-89CF-5E574AD052AB}">
            <File Id="SsrsBarcodeRuntime"
                        Name="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.dll"
                        Checksum="yes"
                        KeyPath="yes" />

            <!--
    Patch the rsreportserver.config file
    Add the following entry;

    <ReportItems>
       <ReportItem Name="Barcode" Type="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.BarcodeImageReportItem, Zen.Barcode.SSRS"/>
    </ReportItems>
    -->
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItemsAdd"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Name="ReportItems"
                                            Sequence="1">
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItem"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Sequence="2">
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItemName"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                                ElementId="RsReportServerReportItem"
                                                Name="Name"
                                                Value="Barcode"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItemType"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                                ElementId="RsReportServerReportItem"
                                                Name="Type"
                                                Value="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.BarcodeImageReportItem, Zen.Barcode.SSRS"
                                                Sequence="4" />
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItemRemove"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Sequence="1"/>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsReportServerReportItemsRemove"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rsreportserver.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems[\[]not(*)[\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Name="ReportItems"
                                            Sequence="2"/>

            <!--
    NOTE: The public key blob here is based on the key in this solution.
    If you change the key (so you can build a private version) then you
    will need to use sn.exe -Tp <assemblyName> to get the full public key
    and replace the key blob below.

    <CodeGroup 
       class="UnionCodeGroup" 
       version="1" 
       Name="ZenBarcodeFullTrust"
       PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
       Description="This code group grants Zen.Barcode.SSRS.dll FullTrust permission.">
       <IMembershipCondition 
          class="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
          version="1"
          PublicKeyBlob="002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010057fead0aec1625
                          2de4b14e772ccadcc845428b276e6fdb3802c0e0218bd6028ca2f5d8c69f5387766df9d058a7dd
                          7cd826bd60565ce21973bcea99e7ae8e997bb87cb743057152334bb720062c218a8e23c29a8c2b
                          62538710d191cb84d85ff733cf921ae83e1ac227555dda968f6d2e73d403bf7e043dfa392173c4
                          5082f1cb" />
    </CodeGroup>
    -->
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                            ElementPath="//CodeGroup[\[]@PermissionSetName=&quot;Execution&quot;[\]][\[]IMembershipCondition[\[]@Zone=&quot;MyComputer&quot;[\]][\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Sequence="1"
                                            Name="CodeGroup">
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupClass"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                                Name="class"
                                                Value="UnionCodeGroup"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupVersion"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                                Name="version"
                                                Value="1"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupName"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                                Name="Name"
                                                Value="ZenBarcodeFullTrust"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupPermission"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                                Name="PermissionSetName"
                                                Value="FullTrust"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupDescription"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroup"
                                                Name="Description"
                                                Value="This code group grants Zen.Barcode.SSRS.dll FullTrust permission."
                                                Sequence="3" />
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyMembership"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                            ElementPath="//CodeGroup[\[]@Name=&quot;ZenBarcodeFullTrust&quot;[\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Name="IMembershipCondition"
                                            Sequence="4">
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyMembershipClass"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyMembership"
                                                Name="class"
                                                Value="StrongNameMembershipCondition"
                                                Sequence="5" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyMembershipVersion"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyMembership"
                                                Name="version"
                                                Value="1"
                                                Sequence="5" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyMembershipKeyBlob"
                                                File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                                ElementId="RsSrvPolicyMembership"
                                                Name="PublicKeyBlob"
                                                Value="002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010057fead0aec16252de4b14e772ccadcc845428b276e6fdb3802c0e0218bd6028ca2f5d8c69f5387766df9d058a7dd7cd826bd60565ce21973bcea99e7ae8e997bb87cb743057152334bb720062c218a8e23c29a8c2b62538710d191cb84d85ff733cf921ae83e1ac227555dda968f6d2e73d403bf7e043dfa392173c45082f1cb"
                                                Sequence="5" />
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="RsSrvPolicyCodeGroupRemove"
                                            File="[ReportServerFolder]rssrvpolicy.config"
                                            ElementPath="//CodeGroup[\[]@PermissionSetName=&quot;Execution&quot;[\]][\[]IMembershipCondition[\[]@Zone=&quot;MyComputer&quot;[\]][\]]"
                                            VerifyPath="//CodeGroup[\[]@Name=&quot;ZenBarcodeFullTrust&quot;[\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            Name="CodeGroup"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Sequence="1">
            </util:XmlConfig>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ReportServerBinFolder"
                                FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.TargetDir)">
        <Component Id="SsrsBarcodeCoreDllComponent"
                             Guid="{13F4CCCC-5B68-402E-9511-26C8F58E3AFC}">
            <File Id="SsrsBarcodeCore"
                        Name="Zen.Barcode.Core.dll"
                        Checksum="yes"
                        KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>

<!-- VS folder fragments -->
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
        <Directory Id="VSIDEFOLDER">
            <Directory Id="PrivateAssembliesFolder"
                                 Name="PrivateAssemblies"
                                 FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.TargetDir)">
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="PrivateAssembliesFolder"
                                FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.TargetDir)">
        <Component Id="VsBarcodeRuntimeDllComponent"
                             Guid="{1E86A556-1266-4F51-901A-617AC7A68640}">
            <File Id="VsBarcodeRuntime"
                        Name="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.dll"
                        Checksum="yes"
                        KeyPath="yes" />

            <!--
    <ReportItems>
        <ReportItem Name="Barcode" Type="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.BarcodeImageReportItem, Zen.Barcode.SSRS" />
    </ReportItems>
    -->
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemsAdd"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            Name="ReportItems"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Sequence="1"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]" />
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemAdd"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Sequence="2"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]">
                <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemName"
                                                ElementId="VsBarcodeReportItemAdd"
                                                File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                                Name="Name"
                                                Value="Barcode"
                                                Sequence="3" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemType"
                                                ElementId="VsBarcodeReportItemAdd"
                                                File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                                Name="Type"
                                                Value="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.BarcodeImageReportItem, Zen.Barcode.SSRS"
                                                Sequence="3" />
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemRemove"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Sequence="1"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]" />
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportItemsRemove"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItems[\[]not(*)[\]]"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Name="ReportItems"
                                            Sequence="2"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="PrivateAssembliesFolder"
                                FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design.TargetDir)">
        <Component Id="VsBarcodeDesigntimeDllComponent"
                             Guid="{60E69B53-D53E-48BC-BFFA-FC708958962A}">
            <File Id="VsBarcodeDesigntime"
                        Name="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design.dll"
                        Checksum="yes"
                        KeyPath="yes" />

            <!--
    <ReportItemDesigner>
        <ReportItem Name="Barcode" Type="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design.BarcodeImageDesigner, Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design" />
    </ReportItemDesigner>
    -->
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignersAdd"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            Name="ReportItemDesigner"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Sequence="5"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]" />
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignerAdd"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Action="create"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="install"
                                            Sequence="6"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]">
                <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignerName"
                                                ElementId="VsBarcodeReportDesignerAdd"
                                                File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                                Name="Name"
                                                Value="Barcode"
                                                Sequence="7" />
                <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignerType"
                                                ElementId="VsBarcodeReportDesignerAdd"
                                                File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                                Name="Type"
                                                Value="Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design.BarcodeImageDesigner, Zen.Barcode.SSRS.Design"
                                                Sequence="7" />
            </util:XmlConfig>
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignerItemRemove"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner"
                                            Name="ReportItem"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Sequence="8"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner/ReportItem[\[]@Name=&quot;Barcode&quot;[\]]" />
            <util:XmlConfig Id="VsBarcodeReportDesignerRemove"
                                            File="[PrivateAssembliesFolder]rsreportdesigner.config"
                                            ElementPath="/Configuration/Extensions"
                                            Name="ReportItemDesigner"
                                            Action="delete"
                                            Node="element"
                                            On="uninstall"
                                            Sequence="9"
                                            VerifyPath="/Configuration/Extensions/ReportItemDesigner[\[]not(*)[\]]" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="PrivateAssembliesFolder"
                                FileSource="$(var.Zen.Barcode.SSRS.TargetDir)">
        <Component Id="VsBarcodeCoreDllComponent"
                             Guid="{B263A5B0-CF13-472A-9712-A0DC5402DE05}">
            <File Id="VsBarcodeCore"
                        Name="Zen.Barcode.Core.dll"
                        Checksum="yes"
                        KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies very much hidden as a comment in the Wix source code.

"*Note: The instance name must be passed to MSIEXEC if installation to the non-default SSRS
instance is desired (using property SSRSINSTANCE)
TODO: Modify WiX dialogs to add a SSRS instance selector page.*"

What this means is that, you should install your msi package using the following command:

**msiexec /i   [path to your .msi package]  SSRSINSTANCE=[Name of your instance]**

The better way to do that is to have a dialog where you can accept  the instance name from the user and make use of it. Unless, you are looking at doing this,  just executing the installer using the above command line should suffice for you.

Also, since you mentioned that you need to modify the source to deploy it on VS2013 and SSRS 2014,  the location of Visual studio and Sql Server reporting services is queried using the windows Registry. 
This is achieved in your source code using **RegistrySearch** tags.

For information about Wix RegistrySearch tag, take a look at :

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html

I do not know if the registry structure created as a result of installing SSRS 2014 and Visual studio 2013 is different from the registry structure for VS2008 and SSRS2008.However, if there are changes in the registry structure, then the  RegistrySearch elements need to be updated to use the correct registry   key paths for the installer to be able to query the registry in the right location.

RegistrySearch  for SSRS:

```
<!--
SsrsKeyName - Determines the registry key name for the SSRS instance.
-->
    <Property Id="SSRSKEYNAME">
      <?if $(var.Platform) = "x86" ?>
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSInstanceKey"
                                      Root="HKLM"
                                      Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS"
                                      Name="[SSRSINSTANCE]"
                                      Type="raw"
                                      Win64="no" />
      <?else ?>
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSInstanceKey"
                                      Root="HKLM"
                                      Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS"
                                      Name="[SSRSINSTANCE]"
                                      Type="raw"
                                      Win64="yes" />
      <?endif ?>
    </Property>

    <!-- 
SSRSFOLDER - Determines the installation folder for the SSRS instance.
-->
    <Property Id="SSRSFOLDER">
      <?if $(var.Platform) = "x86" ?>
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSFolder"
                                      Root="HKLM"
                                      Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SSRSKEYNAME]\Setup"
                                      Name="SQLPath"
                                      Type="directory"
                                      Win64="no" />
      <?else ?>
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetSSRSFolder"
                                      Root="HKLM"
                                      Key="Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\[SSRSKEYNAME]\Setup"
                                      Name="SQLPath"
                                      Type="directory"
                                      Win64="yes" />
      <?endif ?>
    </Property>
```

For the Visual studio, the following registry key might have to be updated(only if required):

```
<Property Id="VSIDEFOLDER">
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetVSFolder"
                                      Root="HKLM"
                                      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Setup\VS"
                                      Name="EnvironmentDirectory"
                                      Type="directory"
                                      Win64="no" />
    </Property>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Were you able to proceed further on your issue?